# Click event on HTML Element of htmlText Property of TextArea

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, event-handling, textarea, movieclip

I have multiple anchor tags created inside the **`htmlText`** property of a `TextArea` object. I want to get the event dispatched whenever user clicks on any one of the anchor tag.

Example code:

```
myTextArea.htmlText = "<a href=\"somelink1\">somelabel1</a><br/><a href=\"somelink2\">somelabel2</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

.[htmlText](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText) is not property of [MovieClip](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html) but [TextField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html)

```
var t:TextField = new TextField();
t.htmlText = "<a href=\"event:my event text\">somelabel1</a>";
this.addChild(t);
t.addEventListener(TextEvent.LINK, onLinkClicked);

function onLinkClicked(e:TextEvent):void {
    trace("Event text:", e.text);
}
```

You can read more about at given pages.

Comment: my bad, you are right, instead of TextField, we are using TextArea and we have multiple links in one string as I mentioned in the question. But the above example you wrote has only one anchor tag. I am not an expert to Actionscript, just got to update few things. Do you have any sample code which works with multiple anchor tags for same textarea?

Comment: This one works with multiple tags. I removed part of text for more clear answer. Where is your problem? If you don't see some "somelabel2" in your text make sure you set `multiline` property to `true`.

Comment: Oh, see [textField](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/controls/TextArea.html#textField)  property. `TextArea` is not `TextField` but it wraps `TexField` instance inside itself so you should have something like `textArea.textField.addEventListener(...)`

Comment: I have a code like this `myTextArea.htmlText = "<a href=\"somelink1\">somelabel1</a><br/><a href=\"somelink2\">somelabel2</a>";
`

Comment: yes and now you need to add listener to text filed. If you want more detailed answer update your question add add more detail to it. What exactly did you tried that which in working?

Comment: Sorry for my broken comment - here is better version:

Comment: yes and now you need to add listener to text filed. If you want more detailed answer update your question and add more detail to it. What exactly did you tried which is not working?